# My flutter appication accidentally catch another application message!! Is that an issue?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning flutter and trying to create a chat app with Flutter and Firebase.
When I'm testing it, I got a message from another app. When I replied to it, my terminal also catch the message with content, timestamp, and created_by information.
Is this a bug? Should I contact the application dev team? Am I in trouble for hacking??
I am confused right now, please help!!

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because the other app might be using `print` statements, and as you are currently debugging apps and is in development mode, it prints the content in your console.

That's why it is always recommended to use `log` instead of `print` during development.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer? I am trying to use `log` in my Swift XCode project and it won't compile; `No exact matches in call to global function 'log'`? What language does this apply to and how do `log` and `print` differ, and how does this help the OP? Can you update the ANSWER with more info?

Comment: The question has a tag of Flutter framework (Dart) language, so this answer is specifically for that.